# Both pattern and color for background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to set both color and pattern for my site background, but I do not know how.
Can someone help me??
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the manual: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/

```
#myElement{
    /* composite statement for background */
    background: #ff0000 url(some url) repeat-x top left;
}

#myElement{
  /* individual statements */
  background: white url("pendant.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: center;
}
```

In both cases, **many** options and combinations available.